# Entity Framework Core Self reference optional property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite v1.0.1.
This is my entity:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get;set;}
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

So i need to configure ParentCategory as an optional property. How can i do this in EF core?
This is my fluent mapping until now:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(e =>
{
    e.HasKey(c => c.CategoryId);

    e.Property(c => c.DateCreated).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    e.Property(c => c.DateModified).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ParentCategoryId` is already optional based on the fact that it is nullable. If it wasn't nullable, it would be required. You don't need to configure it further.

Note, you don't need to configure `CategoryId` as the Key for `Category`. It will be configured as the key because it already follows the naming convention for an entity key.

Comment: And EF will know, that the nullable ParentCategoryID is the foreign key for the property?

Comment: It should do - I haven't tested with EF Core on self-referencing relationships yet - except to check that the approach outlined in my [EF6 article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/255/entity-framework-recipe-hierarchical-data-management) works. To be on the safe side, I recommend renaming `ParentCategory` to just `Parent`, and adding a `Children` property which will be a `List<Category>`.